# How to extract info from each entity of a single class?

Tags: python, class, oop

Using pygame, I have a class using sprite which tosses 10 rectangles from the same point in a random x and y direction and stops them on the ground using imitated gravity and friction. My goal is to print how many pixels  each of the rectangles travelled from the original point, measured from and to their starting- and end -center point.

Since I can run a movement function for every entity via:

```
for aball in ballgroup:
    aball.refresh()
```

I assumed I could extract information from each of the entities the same way.
So this is the function I have in the class:

```
def throwlength(self):
        if self.trigger == True:
            length = abs(self.start_xmid - self.end_xmid)
            return length
```

It triggers once all the rectangles are stationary, start_*x*mid and end_xmid are simply the center of the rectangle before and after the movement. This function is supposed to calculate and return the distance travelled.

And in my running program I have this which runs once all the rectangles are stationary:

```
for aball in ballgroup:
    checklist.append(aball.throwlength())
    break
```

I want to retrieve the individual distance travelled from each ball/rectangle, however I get the same number ten times, the number shared between the ten varies with each run, so I believe it only retrieves the length from a single rectangle.

How can I adjust my code to do this, is there something I'm missing or is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: Use a debugger to put a breakpoint into `throwlength`  and then you can see exactly why the values are all the same. I highly recommend getting acquainted with debugging your code. PyCharm is free and has a really good debugger. [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) is how you use it.

Comment: Due to the `break` in the for-loop it should only append one value.